# How to go to previous location in Visual Studio Code (VS Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I accidentally press any key and the cursor goes somewhere else, how do I return to previous location? What is shortcut key for that?

Any extension that may help.

Answer (score 325, accepted):

This function is called "navigate Back", you find it also in the [Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings) and more accessible within vscode from the keybindings UI.

| OS | default keybinding for `navigateBack` |
| --- | --- |
| Mac | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> |
| Windows | <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> |
| Linux | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> |

| OS | default keybinding for `navigateForward` |
| --- | --- |
| Mac | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> |
| Windows | <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> |
| Linux | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> |

Comment: Great! Also, adding `SHIFT` will reverse the action and take you to the next location, so you can easily go back and forth.

Comment: @Nobita: to go to the next location, you can also use Alt + Right arrow.

Comment: Also be careful that you aren't using any extensions like sublime shortcuts for vscode as that will interfere with the default key bindings of vs code.

Comment: alt + arrow left/right has worked for me to go back and forth also multiple times. The shortcuts in this answer not.

Comment: I wonder just like Windows why these are not `Alt`+`Left`/`Right` for other systems. In Linux, these key combinations don't even seem to be used by any other functionalities and they could have made use of these to make the navigation easier.

Comment: how did i live without this before!??!